# Two entries same category

Tags: templating, categories

I have two different sections that share the same category group that I want to display both on browser at the same time only if the category is the same. Doing that in Craft CMS is possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please add more details to your question? Are you trying to create a related entries view that searches by category in two sections? Is this on a single entry view or an overview entry listing page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible, you need to specify the craft category and set the group parameter on it and fetch the categories with `.all()`.

```
{% set categories = myCategoryQuery.all() %}
```